# Can change colors and other attributes with CSS of SVG images used as background?

Tags: css, svg

I am using a SVG image as background like this:

```
background:url("images/button2.svg") no-repeat 0 0 / 100% 100%;
```

I wonder if I can change the color of the fill and stroke with CSS only so I can have the same image on different places and a different style every time.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't if you use background images. They basically make SVG work like raster images (only scalable).

Comment: I see. Those are bad news. I need to change the color of the SVG for the hover state. Is there any alternate way to do that?

Comment: Have 2 images, one for hover and one not. Swap between the two.

Comment: Is that the only way? That will imply double the images for each one of those. More data to load.

Comment: Use an object or iframe tag to contain the data or make it inline, then you can manipulate it.

Comment: What about using <g ="someid"> and then call it like this background:url("images/button2.svg#someid") no-repeat 0 0 / 100% 100%;

Comment: What do you think that will do? What did it actually do when you tried it?

Comment: I dont know. First I thought it worked but not anymore. I dont know if its a glitch or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it when it is in the background.
You'd better use it in an `<img>` tag and then embed it.
There are already some scripts for that.
I created my own recently:
https://github.com/IskrenStanislavov/svg-embed

Comment: Thank you. But I need it as a background because its a container.